# Behavior of Arrays in bash scripting and zsh shell (Start Index 0 or 1?)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, zsh

I need explenation about the following behavior of arrays in shell scripting:

Imagine the following is given:

```
arber@host ~> ls
fileA fileB script.sh
```

Now i can do the following commands:

```
arber@host ~> ARR=($(ls -d file*))
arber@host ~> echo ${ARR[0]}          # start index 0

arber@host ~> echo ${ARR[1]}          # start index 1
fileA
arber@host ~> echo ${ARR[2]}          # start index 2
fileB
```

But when I do this via **script.sh** it behaves different (Start Index = 0):

```
arber@host ~> cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
ARR=($(ls -d file*))

# get length of an array
aLen=${#ARR[@]}

# use for loop read all items (START INDEX 0)
for (( i=0; i<${aLen}; i++ ));
do
  echo ${ARR[$i]}
done
```

Here the result:

```
arber@host ~> ./script.sh
fileA
fileB
```

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and **zsh**. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Populate your array as `arr=(file*)` and start with `index=0`

Comment: What does `type ls` say in your interactive shell?

Comment: Why are you using `ls`?

Comment: Are you using `zsh`? Arrays in `bash` are 0-indexed; arrays in `zsh` are 1-indexed.

Comment: Your script is definitely executed with `bash` (based on the method of execution and the shebang), but your command-line example indicates you are using `zsh`. What does `echo $ARR` output `fileA` or `fileA fileB`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `zsh`. So that means, that arrays in `zsh` are 1-index? Why?? How does zsh change this behavior of the shell?

Comment: @Arber, zsh is a completely different shell, and it doesn't even *try* to be compatible with bash (or compliant with the POSIX sh spec, except when explicitly in a mode for the purpose -- though the latter is moot for purposes of this question, as arrays aren't a POSIX feature).

Comment: @Arber, ...that said, populating a list from `ls` is basically always bad practice; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you so much for your response. I will read the article.

Comment: Perhaps you might also change the tag from "bash" to "zsh", and/or change "in shell scripting" in the title to "in zsh"? Though if you want your script to only run with zsh, it should also use a `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` shebang or similar.

Comment: I added the tag `zsh` and changed the title a bit. I think it's important for the article to keep showing the initial unawareness about the difference of these two (bash and zsh). Something else: Why everyone "just" comment the question but doesn't add an answer - since it was clear to you? (btw. that's my first question on stackoverflow).

Comment: @Arber Because we didn't *know* you were using `zsh`. It was the most obvious explanation for the behavior we were seeing, but it wasn't necessarily the *only* explanation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

- `bash` array indexing starts at `0` (always)
- `zsh` array indexing starts at `1` (unless [option `KSH_ARRAYS`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Shell-Emulation) is set)

**To always get consistent behaviour, use:**

```
${array[@]:offset:length}
```

---

### Explanation

For code which works in both `bash` and `zsh`, you need to use the `offset:length` syntax rather than the `[subscript]` syntax.

Even for `zsh`-only code, you'll still need to do this (or use `emulate -LR zsh`) since `zsh`'s array subscripting basis is determined by the `KSH_ARRAYS` option.

E.g., to reference the first element in an array:

```
${array[@]:0:1}
```

Here, `array[@]` is all the elements, `0` is the offset (which is *always* 0-based), and `1` is the number of elements desired.

Comment: Thanks, to reference the first **zsh** array elem, I would **$ar[1]** for less typing than your solution, if you do **not need compatibility** between the two shells.

Comment: That's generally true but is dependant on the value of zsh's KSH_ARRAYS option.

Answer (score 13):

[Arrays in Bash are indexed from zero](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html), and [in zsh they're indexed from one](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts).

But you don't need the indices for a simple use case such as this. Looping over `${array[@]}` works in both:

```
files=(file*)
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

In zsh you could also use `$files` instead of `"${files[@]}"`, but that doesn't work in Bash. (And there's the slight difference that it drops empty array elements, but you won't get any from file names.)

---

Also, don't use `$(ls file*)`, it will break if you have filenames with spaces (see [WordSpliting on BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)), and is completely useless to begin with.

The shell is perfectly capable of generating filenames by itself. That's actually what will happen there, the shell finds all files with names matching `file*`, passes them to `ls`, and `ls` just prints them out again for the shell to read and process.

Comment: "... prints them out again for the shell", which in turn will do quote removal and splitting on whitespace characters (or `$IFS` in general), both of which can result in errors or unexpected results.

Comment: @Kusalananda, which is exactly what I mean with things breaking for filenames with spaces, but I'm too lazy to type the whole disclaimer each time. And I don't think it would do quote removal. Globbing and word/field splitting of course.