# Iterate through a list of containers in Azure storage account

Tags: arrays, bash, azure, text, command-line-interface

1. I receive a list of container names from azure storage:
   `raw_containers_string=$(az storage container list --account-name acc-name --account-key 'key_value' --query '[].{name:name}' -otsv)`. Output is:

   ```
   123
   container1
   ```
2. Do text pre-processing so that container names are treated as whole words: `containers=($(echo $raw_containers_string | tr ' ' "\n"))`
3. Assign this to a value `containers` to declare an array:
   `declare -a containers_array=($containers)`
4. I then need to iterate through this array, e.g.

```
  for container in ${containers_array[@]}
  do
    echo "==== Blobs in container $container ===="
    az storage blob list --container-name $container \
      --account-name ${sa_name} \
      --account-key $key \
      --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv
  done
```

**Actual behaviour**

It doesn't work because the first element in the array is an empty symbol and other values are assigned properly:

```
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $containers_array
123 vbm-container
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $containers_array[0]

➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $containers_array[1]
123
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $containers_array[2]
vbm-container
```

**Expected behaviour**

```
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $containers_array
123 vbm-container
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $containers_array[0]
123
➜  bash-az-list-blobs git:(master) ✗ echo $containers_array[1]
vbm-container
```

This is not a duplicate of [Behavior of Arrays in bash scripting and zsh shell (Start Index 0 or 1?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427449/behavior-of-arrays-in-bash-scripting-and-zsh-shell-start-index-0-or-1), since my array is still pushing all elements to the first index, e.g.
`echo $containers_array[0] → 123 vbm-container`

But it has to be

`echo $containers_array[0] → 123`
`echo $containers_array[1] → vbm-container`

Comment: Are you by any chance working in `zsh` shell? There the array starting index is `1` and not `0`. Please see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427449/behavior-of-arrays-in-bash-scripting-and-zsh-shell-start-index-0-or-1/50433774.

Comment: Yes, I use zsh. I could never imagine there is a shell that has array indexes starting from 1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gaurav Mantri for your valuable inputs.  I have added the array index in my for-loop iteration I can be able to ignore the First array index.

I have modified your code snippet to ignore the 1st Index of array

```bash
containers="\n  123 container1"

# convert your string to array
StringToArray=' ' read -r -a containers_array<<< "$containers"


# To ignore the 0th Index of array (To ignore 0th Index use the iteration from 1st Index Eg: ${Array[@]: Your start Index})
  
 for container in ${containers_array[@]:1}
  do
    echo "==== Blobs in container $container ===="
    az storage blob list --container-name $container \
      --account-name ${sa_name} \
      --account-key $key \
      --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv
  done
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Unfiortunatelly, it doesn't work.


`containers=$'123\nvbm-container'`

`StringToArray=' ' read -r -a containers_array<<< "$containers"`
bad option: -a

Comment: I also don't understand what `StringToArray=' ' read -r -a containers_array<<< "$containers"` is intended to do here. I don't see any docs on this syntax

Comment: the bottom line is that I need to transfer this `raw_containers_string=$'123\nvbm-container'` to this `containers=("123" "vbm-container")`

Comment: Refer [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=r-read-command) for usage of read -r -a